# How does generateFromLink work?

Tags: 8

How the **generateFromLink** method works ? And how to use it in the render array.  What is the difference between this method and the other methods used to generate link ?

```
$url = new Url('test_route_1');

$link = new Link('Test', $url);

$generated_link = \Drupal::service('link_generator')->generateFromLink($link);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  First step should always be to simply scan the /core folder for that method. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please update your question with your findings and with more context. Many thanks

Comment: You would typically only use a method marked as `@internal Should not be used in user code.` if you already know exactly what it did (or preferably not use it at all). As leymannx mentioned, you should probably edit the question to provide some context around what you're trying to achieve and why you've identified that method as being useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use this service because it is marked as internal and you shouldn't use any other method to generate links in custom code. Generating a link is like early rendering. See https://www.lullabot.com/articles/early-rendering-a-lesson-in-debugging-drupal-8

Instead add the link as render element to the build array.

Like this examples which also demonstrates how you can build nested render elements, here an image as link title:

```
      $link_title = [
        '#theme' => 'image',
        '#uri' => $image,
        '#alt' => $label,
      ];
      $image_link = [
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => $link_title,
        '#url' => Url::fromUri($link_href),
        '#options' => [
          'attributes' => ['class' => ['feed-image']],
        ],
      ];

      $build[$id]['image'] = $image_link;
```

Example from */core/modules/aggregator/src/FeedViewBuilder.php*